# В фуллстэк приложении после регистрации не перебрасывает на следующую страницу

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, nestjs

Уже больше недели не могу решить проблему, я задеплоил свое full stack приложение на **Vercel, Render**. Суть такова пользователь заходит на страницу регистрации, регистрируются потом входит в аккаунт и попадает на следующую страницу, сессия не продолжается.
**На локалхост все работает**.Когда я деплоил сервер и клиент написал все переменные которые были в .env файле, адрес сервера и подключения клиента и сервера в **main.ts**.

Адрес клиента - https://lifeperfect.vercel.app/
Адрес сервера - https://shop-server-my-shop.onrender.com/

**И в консоли ошибка**

```
main.js?attr=80u-c98TFKi_ig64-4uPxkZ48XSr1gX6n9LbaNDahCzqb9vqS5OuYXu1dvTDGKzpk95aUxR4AqRAMsq59GAnZA:3577 
        
        
        GET https://shop-server-my-shop.onrender.com/users/login-check 403
```

**Адрес клиента - shop-fullstack-client.vercel.app сервера - shop-server-my-shop.onrender.com**

Comment: И забыл оставить

Comment: Адрес клиента - https://shop-fullstack-client.vercel.app/ сервера - https://shop-server-my-shop.onrender.com/